# How to get buttons fixed irrespective of the contents hidden or not in a card in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

https://codepen.io/Adellii/pen/VBEQbo?&editors=101

The current code moves the buttons to the bottom when user clicks on yes in the radio button.How do I get the buttons fixed  in the bottom?

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-layout>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
        <v-card height="280">
          <v-radio-group  v-model="content">
            <v-radio label="Yes"  value="yes" name="yes"></v-radio>
            <v-radio label="No" value="no" name="no"></v-radio>
          </v-radio-group>
          <div class="x" v-show="content === 'yes'">
          <v-text-field  label="Regular" placeholder="Placeholder"></v-text-field>
          <v-text-field label="Regular" placeholder="Placeholder"></v-text-field>
          </div>

          <v-card-actions>
            <v-btn flat color="orange">Share</v-btn>
            <v-btn flat color="orange">Explore</v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also show us the css code affecting this component?

Comment: It doesn't have any css code but some javascript in the codepen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there are no v-card component props to achieve this.
So just add some css:

```
.flexcard {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

<v-card class="flexcard">
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyJMzM)

Note that this works in your provided example for placing buttons at the bottom. In case your CSS is different in your project I'm not sure what you would like to do with other elements inside card.  So you might need to add something like `<v-spacer></v-spacer>` or `class="grow"` or `class="shrink"` to some elements inside v-card to fit your style.
[Example with bigger v-card height](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xJyyRQ)